# How to replace bookmarks text in docx file with image in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, ms-word, ms-office

I am using docxmarks to replace the bookmarks with text
 in docx file. But it is not giving any information on replacing bookmark with image.

Here is my code for docxmarks.

```
const replacements = {
  DocNumber: "CR1234123",
  DocRevision: "CS"
}

docxmarks(docx, replacements).then((data) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(path, data);
});
```

Comment: Have you checkd the following link https://docxtemplater.com/modules/image/ ?

Comment: Yes,I have checked that module. but it replaces placeholder with image and not Bookmark of docx file.